# Anatomically Correct Stitch

Tags: biology

We all remember the iconic alien genetic experiment from "Lilo and Stitch", correct? Well, I was wondering what kind of biological traits Jumba might have used to give him his various abilities, like his durability, his ability to lift up to three thousand times his own weight, his retractable body parts, etc.?

Comment: No, we might not all remember whatever you are referring to. Please state all the specific requirements (What kind of durability? What retractable body parts? What "etc."?) in the question and in addition possibly link to some sort of Wiki article with additional information.

Comment: We can't remember something we have never seen.

Comment: There are plenty of "Anatomically Correct" questions here in WB.SE. Please refer to one of them when formulating your question! [Medusa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/anatomically-correct-medusa); [Cyclops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30163/anatomically-correct-cyclops); [Phoenix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28458/anatomically-correct-phoenix)

Comment: @Vincent  he is talking about stitch from lilo and stitch. If you haven't seen the movie then here is his wiki fandom http://liloandstitch.wikia.com/wiki/Stitch_(626)?li_source=LI&li_medium=wikia-footer-wiki-rec . If you have seen the movie then i have no idea why you're saying that

Comment: still, this is a pretty badly worded question

Answer (score 1):

While the parts about insane strength and durability are answered in other questions, his retractable arms seem unique enough to warrant an answer.
There are two ways I can think off to do this:

1. Tentacles like a snail’s eyestalk
2. Turtle-neck system

So while the connection and arm might be too weak to achieve the strength of stitch’s arms, but perhaps his back spines would use this method. It consists of a simple muscular tube with a retractor muscle in the centre, which pulls the tentacle into the body.

The stronger system would be the turtle’s, in which they have a recess where the arm can be pulled into, tho the hand would probably still be mostly visible.

Comment: What other questions?